# Why is PHP giving off a undefined variable message for this code?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have this code. It's just for testing purposes, so you don't need to tell me to use parameter binding and prepared statements and PDO to avoid SQL Injection.

```
foreach($dd->getElementsByTagName("ReportItem") as $elmt){
    foreach ($elmt->childNodes as $node){
        if($node->nodeName==="ModuleName")
            $name = $node->nodeValue;

            if($result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from technology_info where name = $name")){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){

                    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into technology_info(id,name,tool_id) values(null,$name,'2')");
                    //ERROR: Undefined variable: name 

                }

            }
        }
}
```

This is what the code is meant to accomplish: if variable `$name` is a value that is already in the database, do nothing. Otherwise, add it to the database.

However, I'm getting an error message: **Notice: Undefined variable: name in /var/www/teste/index5.php**

I mean, the variable **is** there. Any idea what might be happening?

Comment: echo the variable after the $name = $node->nodeValue; to see what the output is

Comment: well as the if says $name is not always set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$name` is only being set `if($node->nodeName==="ModuleName")`.  That if statement only applies to that one line, yet the code below it (the mysql statements) will continue to run regardless.

Answer (score 1):

`$node->nodeValue` is probably `null`, which sets `$name` to `null`. PHP would render that as undefined.

Comment: The `if` statement right above the assignment would prevent this.

Comment: Also, `null` is certainly not the same as "undefined"

Comment: @thetaiko that checks `nodeName`, not `nodeValue`, and PHPs looseness sometimes renders null as undefined.

Comment: my bad on the nodeName/nodeValue.  You're correct there.  But I will stand by my assertion that PHP will never render `null` as undefined.

Comment: @thetaiko I have had a couple cases where this happened. It's rare and depends on whether the variable is an object or not (and more stuff, I don't remember my exact case).

Answer (score 1):

You left out a set of squiggly brackets

```
foreach($dd->getElementsByTagName("ReportItem") as $elmt){
foreach ($elmt->childNodes as $node){
    if($node->nodeName==="ModuleName")

    { // *** You left this out 

        $name = $node->nodeValue;

        if($result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from technology_info where name = $name")){
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){

                mysqli_query($conn,"insert into technology_info(id,name,tool_id) values(null,$name,'2')");
                //ERROR: Undefined variable: name 

            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

Also going to need some quotes around $name in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Well not always if $node->nodeName doesn't equal "ModuleName" then the $name variable never gets created. Try defining your $name variable outside your loops or even just outside your if statement.

Answer (score 0):

$name is out of scope.

Try

```
foreach($dd->getElementsByTagName("ReportItem") as $elmt){
    foreach ($elmt->childNodes as $node){
        if($node->nodeName==="ModuleName"){
            $name = $node->nodeValue;
            if($result=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from technology_info where name = $name")){
                if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==0){
                    mysqli_query($conn,"insert into technology_info(id,name,tool_id) values(null,$name,'2')");
                    //ERROR: Undefined variable: name 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```